# How to uninstall ROCM previous version and reinstall ROCM 4.2 version

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics, blender, opencl

My main objective is to get OpenCl installed on my Ubuntu 20.04 given that I have a AMD-Radeon GPU so that I use render on Blender. As Blender does not see OpenCL, the rendering is presently done with my CPU. Before dealing with OpenCL, ROCM needs to be replaced to 4.2 version. Unfortunately no direct update is possible.

1. I did a research on YouTube and I found an explanation https://youtu.be/efKjfBkjPlM The presenter states that ROCM needs to be installed leading the viewer to the installation guide https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html.
2. The guide mention as prerequirement:  *Ubuntu 20.04.2 HWE*. It also states that *AMD ROCm only supports Long Term Support (LTS) versions of Ubuntu*. I believe I have the LTS version. How to check this?
3. The guide recommends *a Complete Reinstallation OF AMD ROCm V4.2* as  *upgrade from previous version is not supported*. CHeck https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html#complete-reinstallation-of-amd-rocm-v4-2-recommended. I am stock right here.

How to uninstall previous ROCM version and reinstall ROCM V4.2? Any chance Ubuntu 20.04 has the ROCm V4.2? How can I check this?

Thx in advance for your input.

Comment: 2: 20.04.x is an LTS release of Ubuntu. It's as simple as that.

Comment: 3: Check your package version using `apt list rocm-opencl`. If you need to uninstall ROCm, see https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html#uninstalling-rocm-packages-from-ubuntu

Comment: I did run "apt list rocm-opencl" the return was "listing... done".

Comment: If nothing is listed, then you don't have that package installed. Obviously, if you don't have that package installed, then you don't need to remove it.